# How to create a function and pass in variable length argument list?

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, variadic-functions

We can create a function `p` in the following code:

```
var p = function() { };
if (typeof(console) != 'undefined' && console.log) {
    p = function() { console.log(arguments); };
}
```

but the arguments are passed like an array to `console.log`, instead of passed one by one as in

```
console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], ...
```

Is there a way to expand the arguments and pass to console.log like the way above?

**Note that** if the original code were

```
var p = function() { };
if (typeof(console) != 'undefined' && console.log) {
    p = console.log;
}
```

then it works well on Firefox and IE 8 but not on Chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Function.apply()](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/apply.html):

```
console.log.apply(console, arguments);
```