# Invoke function with variable argument length

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a function and pass in variable length argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778513/how-to-create-a-function-and-pass-in-variable-length-argument-list)

I want to call the `console.log` with variable argument list

```
console.log("a","b")
console.log("a","b","c")
```

but i get the arguments from an array:

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
```

and i want to pass as single variables not as a complete array.
so `console.log(arr)` is not what i am looking for,`console.log(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2])` is also bad because i dont know the array length ofc.

How can i do that?

*the `console.log` is only an example, i would use this in different problems*

---

UPDATE

[How to create a function and pass in variable length argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778513/how-to-create-a-function-and-pass-in-variable-length-argument-list) **is not good.** because according to the answer

```
function dump(a,b) {
  console.log("a:"+a,"b:"+b);
}

var asd = [1,2,3]

dump.call(this,asd)
```

should give an output: `a:1,b:2` instead of `a:[1,2,3] b:undefined`

---

UPDATE:

maybe my question was not clear enough, sorry.

The console.log is only a **example** of variable argument invoking

i want to use the same method for **different problems**

look at this example:

```
function Sum() {
  var temp = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;++i) {
     temp+= arguments[i];
  }
  return temp;
}
```

and i want to call with different arguments which are in an array.

```
var test1 = [1,2,3];
var test2 = [4,5,6];

var a = Sum.call(this,test1) //this gives an output "01,2,3"

var b;
for(var i=0;i<test2.length;++i) {
  b = Sum(test2[i])
} //this is also bad because it only returns 6 at the last invoke.
```

Comment: It is a duplicate. Both questions are how to pass an array of arguments to a function as separate arguments. Nowhere in the other question or answer is `Function.call` even mentioned. Do you mean to ask 'why does `dump.call(this,asd)` result in an output of "a:[1,2,3] b:undefined"?'

Comment: You keep using CALL. Use APPLY. Do Sum.apply(this,test1) and see what you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
console.log.apply(console, arr);
```

This answers the question you asked. If you intended to ask:

> Why does `dump.call(this,asd)` result in an output of "a:[1,2,3] b:undefined"?

The answer (which any documentation will tell you) is that [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) is variadic, and any arguments after the first are passed to the function, whereas `Function.apply` takes only two arguments: a value for `this` in the applied function and an array of arguments to pass to the function.

In other words, `Function.call` is equivalent to:

```
function (self) {
    var args = [].slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
    return this.apply(self, args)
}
```

Comment: sorry. i used call instead of apply. im a little tired

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log.apply(console, [stuffs])
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update, this modification will work:

```
function dump(a,b) {
  console.log("a:"+a,"b:"+b);
}

var asd = [1,2,3]

dump.apply(this,asd)
```

Note that you need to use "apply" rather than "call".
But your function is dictating how many arguments to output (console.log("a:"+a,"b:"+b)), so this is of limited value. Can you please try to clearly explain why console.log.apply(console, asd) doesn't give you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean... but javascript is a dynamic languange and you can just pass around dynamic objects. So can you just do something like this:

> var obj = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"};
>   console.log(obj);

The object 'obj' can contain as many properties as you need and can be passed into any function as a single argument.