# JavaScript pass array as individual arguments to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem where I have function with parameters and I have an array of the values associated with the parameters.

```
var myFunction = function(argument_0, argument_1 ) {
//do stuff
}
var arguments = new Array();
arguments[0] = "value0";
arguments[1] = "value1";
```

How would I go about passing that array in the same format to the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a function and pass in variable length argument list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778513/how-to-create-a-function-and-pass-in-variable-length-argument-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
myFunction.apply(null, arguments);
```

Comment: spot on.

Thanks very much.